# Postgresq array to object value

Tags: json, postgresql

i have been trying to build an object from my table, actually i have a query that returns this:

[image]

how can i convert this result to:

```
answerId | json
1|{"en":["Autoimmune","Bronchitis","COPD","Cancer","Cardiovascular","Diabetes","Pulmonary fibrosis","None of the above"],"es":["Autoinmunes","Bronquitis","Cardiovasculares","Cáncer","Diabetes","EPOC","Fibrosis pulmonar","Ninguna de las anteriores"]}
2|{"en":["Yes","No"],"es":["Si","No"]}
```

thank you to every one who can try to helpme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [`json_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT "answerId", json_object_agg(code, answers) AS "json"
FROM myTable
GROUP BY "answerId"
```

Comment: Man, i really do not understand the documentation good enough, thank you for answering!